# React componentDidMount not setting states before page loads

Tags: arrays, reactjs, axios, mern

Working on a MERN application, I have a componentDidMount that uses axios to retrieve from the backend some Ids and retrieve product info(prods) from the ids. However the states in my application are still empty when the page is loaded initially, instead I'll have to make a change to state before the states are set.

I believe it might have something to do with having an array mapping in the componenDidMount, I could change the backend so in node. However i would like to see if anything could be done in the frontend first.

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get("/api/featureds")
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    featureIds: response.data
                });

                response.data.map(({ prodId, _id }) =>
                    axios
                        .get("/api/prods/" + prodId)
                        .then(response => {
                            if (response.data == null) {
                            } else {
                                                                this.state.featureTempList.push(response.data);
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        })
                );

                this.setState({
                    featureProds: this.state.featureTempList
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to set state like this?

```
this.state.featureTempList.push(response.data)
```

State should be set by `this.setState()`.

So you can try doing this:

```
this.setState((oldState) => ({
    featureTempList: oldState.featureTempList.push(response.data)
});
```

Just remember to set featureTempList to state when you initialize:

```
state = {
    featureTempList: []
}
```

Comment: Yup this will help,  originally templist was a variable declared within the componentDidMount, thanks.